# create new column based on whether another column contains each row name

Tags: python, pandas

trying to use pandas to iterate through each row, evaluating whether the row's column B value contains any of the values in column A, to then populate a new column C, D, E... corresponding to each value in row A. The code below is what I'd otherwise have to do to get the same result, but here I'd need to know beforehand what values might be present in row A.

```
d = {'country': ["USA", "China", "Singapore"], 'allies': ["Turkey, UK, France, India", "DPRK, Singapore", "USA, China"]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

df["USAally"] = df['allies'].map(lambda x: 1 if "USA" in x else 0)
df["Chinaally"] = df['allies'].map(lambda x: 1 if "China" in x else 0)
df["Singaporeally"] = df['allies'].map(lambda x: 1 if "Singapore" in x else 0)
```

Comment: Please post a sample input dataframe along with your expected output for this sample data.

Comment: edited the original post, thanks

Comment: @stallionic, If any of the below post answer's your question you can [`mark as accepted`](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's try this, using `series.unique` to identify unique countries followed by `str.contains` to check if it exists.

```
for c in df.country.unique():
    df[f'{c}_Aally'] = df.allies.str.contains(c).astype(int)
    
df
Out[20]: 
     country                     allies  USA_Aally  China_Aally  Singapore_Aally
0        USA  Turkey, UK, France, India         0           0               0
1      China            DPRK, Singapore         0           0               1
2  Singapore                 USA, China         1           1               0
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `get_dummies` here to do this efficiently:

```
dummies = (df['allies'].str.get_dummies(sep=', ')
                       .reindex(df['country'].unique(), axis=1)
                       .add_suffix('_ally'))
df.join(dummies)                                             

     country                     allies  USA_ally  China_ally  Singapore_ally
0        USA  Turkey, UK, France, India         0           0               0
1      China            DPRK, Singapore         0           0               1
2  Singapore                 USA, China         1           1               0
```

Where,

```
dummies

   USA_ally  China_ally  Singapore_ally
0         0           0               0
1         0           0               1
2         1           1               0
```

Comment: @sushanth thank you, +1'd you already, but try to avoid loopy solutions where you can ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a generalization of your code, by first taking all of the unique letters that appear in the `letter` column, and then by looping through them individually and doing essentially what you're doing above, for each.

```
complete_letter_set = set(''.join(df['letter'])
for l in complete_letter_set:
    df[f"letter{l}exists"] = df['letter'].map(lambda x: int(l in x))
```

Note that I've simplified the condition `1 if A in x else 0` to just `int(l in x)`, because `int(True) == 1` and `int(False) == 0` anyway.